# How do i get uniprotkb given pdb id?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I need to get information about length and domain structure of a particular protein, for example 1btk. For this I need to get UniprotKB, how can I do it?

from web site http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore.do?structureId=1BTK

[image: uniprotkb]

the UniprotKB is 'Q06187'

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

you may use urllib2 for download pdb file, next to use regular expression for extract the Uniprot id

```
url_template = "http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/files/{}.pdb"

protein = "1BTK"
url = url_template.format(protein)

import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
pdb = response.read()
response.close()  # best practice to close the file

import re
m = re.search('UNP\ +(\w+)', pdb)
m.group(1)
# you get 'Q06187'
```

**bonus**, if you wish parser the pdb file:

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
parser = PDBParser()
structure = parser.get_structure(protein, response)
response.close()  # best practice to close the file
header = parser.get_header()
trailer = parser.get_trailer()
#info about protein in structure, header and trailer
```